# performing input and output concurrently using multithreading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
import threading
import time
dat = ["it1","it2","it3","it4","it5","it6","it7","it8","it9","it10"]
def fun1():
    for i in range(len(dat)):
        print(dat[i])
t1=threading.Thread(target=fun1)
t1.start
def fun2():
    while True:
        x=input()
        print(x)
fun2()
t1.join()
```

Not running concurrently
I want bot **fun1** and **fun2** to run concurrently, such that even the **fun1** displays text and **fun2** allows to take input

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start the thread, `t1.start()` (not `t1.start`):

```
import threading
import time

dat = ["it1", "it2", "it3", "it4", "it5", "it6", "it7", "it8", "it9", "it10"]


def fun1():
    for i in dat:
        print(i)


def fun2():
    while True:
        x = input()
        print(x)


def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=fun1)
    t1.start()

    fun2()
    t1.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```